# How to redirect python OS system call to a file?

Tags: python, plugins, yum

I have no idea why the below code is not working. The file arch_list does not get created or anything written to it. The commands work fine when run in the terminal alone.

```
from yum.plugins import PluginYumExit , TYPE_CORE, TYPE_INTERACTIVE
import os

requires_api_version = '2.3'
plugin_type = (TYPE_CORE, TYPE_INTERACTIVE)

ip_vm = ['192.168.239.133']

def get_arch():
        global ip_vm
        os.system("uname -p > ~/arch_list")
        for i in ip_vm:
                cmd = "ssh thejdeep@"+i+" 'uname -p' >> ~/arch_list"
                print cmd
                os.system(cmd)

def init_hook(conduit):
        conduit.info(2,'Hello World !')
        get_arch()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think os.system() will return to stdout in that case.  You may try using subprocess.call() with the appropriate parameters.

Edit: Actually I think I remember seeing similar behaviour with ssh when running in a standard bash loop.  You might try adding a -n to your ssh call.. I think that is the solution I used years ago in bash.

I just ran your code and it works fine for me, writing to the local arch file.  I suspect adding more than one host to your list is where you start having problems.  What version of python are you running? I'm on 2.7.6.

Answer (score 0):

os.system() will not redirect stdout and stderr.

You can use subprocess modules Popen to set the stdout and stderr to a file descriptor or a pipe.

For example:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> child1 = subprocess.Popen(["ls","-l"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> print child1.stdout.readlines()
```

You can replace `subprocess.PIPE` to any valid file descriptor you opened for write. or you could pick up some lines to the file. It's your call.